# Как прокинуть переменную в представление

Tags: yii2

Такой вопрос, как прокинуть переменную флаг в представление модального окна? И как к нему обратиться. На данный момент прокидываю туда data атрибут, данный атрибут перехватывается в js обработчике (лежит в assets модуля) и записывается в this. Эту переменную удается передать как значение инпута (), но не знаю, как к нему обратиться, чтобы по его условию скрыть часть контента формы.

Вот кнопка вызова формы

```
<button @click.nostop="selectRate($event)"
                                            class="btn btn-danger btn-block w-auto-md d-md-inline-block"
                                            data-a-event="bcBT11"
                                            data-toggle="modal"
                                            data-target="#payment-form-modal" data-rate="10.00" data-subscription="1" data-title='тариф"'>
                                        <?= Yii::t('app','Buy tariff')?>
                                    </button>
```

Вот обработчик

```
module.exports = {
init: function(){
    var cleave;
    if(document.getElementById('cps_phone') !== null)
    {
        cleave = new Cleave('#cps_phone',{
            prefix: '+7',
            phone: true,
            phoneRegionCode: 'ru'
        });
    }

    alight.directives.al.receipt = function(scope, element, expression, env) {
        this.watch(expression, function(value) {
            env.changeDetector.setValue('receipt.customerContact',value.replace(/\s/g,''));
        });
    };
    alight.bootstrap(['#al-application'],{

        title:'',

        sum:'1200.00',

        cps_phone:'+7',

        subscription: 0,

        aEventName:'t',

        showInfo : false,

        selectRate:function(event){
            var data = event.target.dataset;
            this.sum = data.rate;
            this.title = data.title;
            this.showInfo = data.info === 'true';
            this.subscription = data.subscription || "0";
            delete(data);
            return true;
        },
        setAName:function(event){
            this.aEventName = event.target.dataset.aEventName;
        }
    });
    return this;
},
```

Вот само представление

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\MaskedInput;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use Yii;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'payment-form',
    'options'=>['data-target'=>'payment-form'],
    'action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/frontend/payment/create']),
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
])?>

    <input name="amount" value="{{sum}}" type="hidden">
    <input name="product" type="hidden" value='{{title}}'>
    <input name="subscription" type="hidden" value="{{subscription}}">
    <?=$form->field($model, 'cps_phone',['enableLabel'=>false])->textInput(['placeholder'=>$model->getAttributeLabel('cps_phone'),'class'=>'form-control','al-value'=>"cps_phone"])?>
    <?=$form->field($model, 'cps_email')->textInput(['placeholder'=>$model->getAttributeLabel('cps_email')])->label(false)?>
    <?=$form->field($model, 'cps_promo')->textInput(['placeholder'=>$model->getAttributeLabel('cps_promo')])->label(false)?>
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Buy tariff'),['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'name' => 'submit_buy', 'value' => 'go_to_buy'])?>
    <p class="small" style="margin-top:10px;">
        Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете согласие на <?=Html::a('хранение и обработку персональных данных', ['/frontend/main/page','page'=>'personal'],['target'=>'_blank'])?>
    </p>
    <br>
    <div>
        // контент который нужно скрыть в зависимости от subscription
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end()?>
```

Comment: кто рендерит представление? обратиться вы хотите из js к нему или из php?

Comment: Его рендерит другое представление ``<?=$this->render('/payment/forms/_payment_form', ['model'=>$model])?>``

Comment: Хочу обратиться из самого представления (то есть из php)

Comment: а вы его передаете в представление, где хотите его использовать из _payment_form ?

Comment: ``data-subscription="1"`` ну я вот так собирался его передать. Мне нужно чтоб он прокидывался при клике по кнопке с определенным тарифом. Далее он доступен как вэлью инпута ``<input name="subscription" type="hidden" value="{{subscription}}">``, но не как не могу достучаться для проверки условия до него. Пытался и через $this и через Yii переменную.

Comment: вы говорите что нужное представление рендерится из _payment_form, как это происходит? через $this->render?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: получается так, что на странице с кнопками тарифов рендерится _modal_payment_form, а в нем уже рендерится _payment_form

Comment: вот в этом рендере вам и надо через параметры передать нужную величину =)

Comment: только мне надо передать по клику на тариф.

Comment: я запутался... =)